# Firebase childbyAutoId returns the same strange key every time

Tags: ios, firebase

When using childByAutoId, something really strange happens. Instead of getting a unique id, I get the following key every time:

```
-------------------0
```

I know keys are generated with client side timestamps, so I tried running my code through the iOS simulator and an actual device, same result though.

I don't do anything interesting in my code, but here it is for reference:

```
func sendRandomMessage() {
        let firebaseRootRef = Firebase(url:firebaseRootUrl)
        let newMessageRef = firebaseRootRef.childByAutoId()
        println(newMessageRef.key)
    }
```

I'm using Firebase 2.3.0

Comment: I have a temporary workaround: reverting to Firebase 2.2.2 solves the problem.

Comment: *[Disclaimer: I work at Firebase]* Hey David, thanks for the clear report and regression check. We just released version 2.3.1 of the Firebase SDK for iOS, which fixes this problem. https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/changelog.html

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the Firebase SDK for iOS 2.3.0 that caused this problem.

It has been fixed in 2.3.1. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/changelog.html